# How to handle pop-up in Chrome Selenium webdriver - Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup

I was using a script to extract some data from the [italian morningstar website](https://www.morningstar.it/it/) and it was working fine. Although since few months, it is appearing a pop-up (caches) straight when I open the webpage.

I used to handle the pop-up by referencing the html element and close it. This method was working fine for a while, then I don't know why since few weeks ago every time I close the popup by accepting all the cookies and I browse into the webpage it continues to reappear (Even if I try to close the pop-up manually!).

If I navigate through Chrome, once I accept the cookies it stops showing, but with selenium webdriver if I accept the cookies the popup continues to show in the same internet session. I tried everything, including importing all the cookies from Chrome but nothing changed.

Do you have a suggestion?

[Here is the pop-up showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHhVL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to pop up and close it if its a html popup. If its not, you must use some autoit/automac or something similar depending on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

You coud try something like

```
     public static void PopUp()
    {
        _webDriver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
    }
```